# What's the point of Granger causality if we can just fit a VAR model?

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression, granger-causality

I've read in multiple places that it's a good idea to run a Granger causality test before fitting a VAR model to a set of time series. Suppose I'm interesting in determining which of the $n$ time series $X_{1t}, X_{2t}, \ldots, X_{nt}$ are "Granger causes" of time series $X_{0t}$, then I can run a Granger causality test $n$ on the pairs $(X_{1t}, X_{0t}), (X_{2t}, X_{0t}), \ldots, (X_{nt}, X_{0t})$ and then throw out the series that are not causes. I can the fit a VAR model on the remaining series.

But can't I just fit a VAR model to all $n+1$ series, and then discard those series for which all lags have insignificant p-values (relative to $X_{0t}$) ?

What is typically done in practice when we have many time series and are interested in modelling one in particular?

Comment: hi: insignficant p-values and granger causaility tests are not a one to one mapping. also, the significance tests in a VAR are going to be quite tricky to interpret because the test-statistics  depend on whether they are conditional on the other variables being in the model or not.  In practice, I don't know what the best approach is but  I imagine that lutkepohl's book must cover how it's done.

Comment: Thanks. Which book are you referring to exactly?

Comment: Hi: Unless things have changed in that 5 or so years, this is kind of the bible for VARS. https://www.amazon.com/New-Introduction-Multiple-Time-Analysis/dp/3540262393/ref=sr_1_1?crid=HIG8QKY1VZBO&dchild=1&keywords=lutkepohl&qid=1595338391&sprefix=lutke%2Caps%2C303&sr=8-1